# how to read the text of an image element which is in the data-val-required attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below html element in my page and i want to read the text of the image tag which is in the data-val-required.

```
<input id="Title" name="Title" type="text" data-val-required="<img class='validateicon'            
       src='https://mysprt/Content/Images/cert.png'/>
       <font color='Red'>*</font>This is sample text" />
```

I could read the src attribute using the below . But what is the way to read the text("this is sample text") of that img element ?

```
$($('#Title').data('val-required')).attr('src');
```

Comment: your html is not valid.

Comment: You need to HTML encode the HTML in the data-attribute. However it is much better practice to not store HTML in there at all. It is needless bloat. Create the HTML for the validation error warning when the required event is raised.

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification in the structure and it can be done. Find the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rLRHs/

html:

```
<input id="Title" name="Title" type="text" data-val-required="<img class='validateicon' src='https://mysprt/Content/Images/cert.png'/>
<font color='Red'>*</font><span>This is sample text</span>" />
```

JS

```
var c = $('#Title').data('val-required');

c = c.substring(c.indexOf("<span>")+6, c.indexOf("</span>"));
```